# what does do telemetryproxy.html file when loading office add-in?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

my outlook add-in that run on custom exchange server getting following error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

resource is 
*https://telemetryservice.firstpartyapps.oaspapps.com/telemetryservice/telemetryproxy.html* file.

what is the purpose of using this file by office js ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telemetryproxy is a deprecated metrics tool. Some older Exchange instances still reference it, but this failure should not affect the development or use of your add-in.

Comment: Do you know how to remove it so I don't get the error every time I run my app?

Comment: If it is deprecated, why is office.js still calling it? (returns error "unknown host"